# Google App Engine: How do I serve different content to different subdomains within one App?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a GAE app set up to serve static HTML from a domain I own.  I also configured GAE to map subdomain "m" to the app, which so far shows the same HTML as the "www" subdomain.

How do I tell the app to serve static files from a different folder within the app's code repository when the "m" subdomain is requested?

Answer (score 0):

If you end up not being able to tell from within the servlet, simply serve a javascript which will call your servlet passing the window url. Then serve based on that.